# IIS rewrite rule - not working for first level of url pattern

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

We are trying to add a rewrite rule matching a regular pattern to our wordpress blog using IIS10 (in Windows Server 2019). However the rule is not applying on the first part of the url scheme.

`<match url="^blog/(.*)$" />`

In this case, the rewrite works for **https://example.com/blog/article1** but not for **https://example.com/blog/** and is giving us 404 error. Have tried the following with no luck:

- Ensure ARR module is installed and Enable proxy is ticked.
- Created separate rewrite rule above the existing rule for /blog
  `<match url="^(blog|blog/)$" />`
- Created **redirect** rule for blog to blog/news and then the rewrite rule works. But we would like to preserve the /blog url on the browser.

Here is the rewrite rule that we are trying to crack and would appreciate some suggestions to get it working. Thank you

```
 <rule name="wordpress-rewrite" stopProcessing="true">  
      <match url="^blog/(.*)$" /> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://blog.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" /> 
 </rule>
```

Comment: You rule rewrite  https://example.com/blog/ to https://blog.example.com/blog/. Is that expected behavior？ If it is not the expected URL, what it should looks like?

Comment: The expected behavioud would be to **blog.example.com/blog/index.php**; but have got a rule on wordpress server to rewrite blog.example.com/blog to the above url.

Comment: What about use URL rewrite rule to achieve this directly? Because I'm not sure whether the rewrite can be done twice.

Comment: Thanks J; we tried that still /blog gives 404 and /blog/* works which seems very weird